# Synonym for nirvanic

Tags: synonyms

To me, nirvanic sounds like a butchery of nirvana. Is there any adjective describing a feeling of nirvana? You know, the serenity/transcendence after meditating for a long time. I know I just listed a few but do y'all have any more?

EDIT: I'd like this synonym to be used to describe a kind of enlightened connection with a person after having a really deep conversation with them.

Comment: It is the tradition of the English language to butcher other languages, and then pick and splice to form new words.

Answer (score 1):

*Sublime* might work for ya, according to Merriam-Webster:

> : very beautiful or good : causing strong feelings of admiration or wonder
>
> : complete or extreme

Comment: I would recommend against sublime due to the wide variety of meanings it can have.

Comment: virmaior, I recommend that you reconsider your awfully strong take on my previous comment here: I share hardly more than an idea or two, thanks.

Comment: I'm definitely not trying to discourage contribution or quibble pointlessly, but *sublime* is a difficult word to use: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-aesthetics/#2.7. Thus, I would recommend using a different word to express what the asker wants.

Comment: You undoubtedly are discouraging contribution...and encouraging redundant language. You _should_ drop "would" from your skeptical recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Here in India, where the term originated, a common synonym for Nirvana is bliss.

In Buddhism, the word Nirvana denotes the state of transcendence wherein an individual soul merges into the great soul (God, The Force, The Universal Consciousness) https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nirvana.

The word Nirvanic would not be used here to describe a connection between two people. Perhaps your intended meaning would better be conveyed by the English word "magical."

Answer (score 0):

“Nirvanic” is the adjective in Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary: a nirvanic experience.

From thesaurus.com, here are a multiplicity of synonyms for “nirvanic”:

Synonyms: absent, absent-minded, abstracted, airheaded, amnemonic, amnesic, asleep on the job, bemused, careless, distracted, dreamy, heedless, inattentive, lax, like an absent-minded professor, looking out window, mooning, moony, neglectful, negligent, nirvanic, not on the job, oblivious, out of it, out to lunch, pipe dreaming, preoccupied, remiss, slack, sloppy, unmindful, unwitting, woolgathering

Comment: How bizarre. Each and every one of those ‘synonyms’ are extremely negatively loaded and seem not to fit with the meaning of _nirvanic_ at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think the point is that *nirvana* not being an English/Western concept, these are synonyms of the 'fact' but display the Western opinion of it.

Answer (score 0):

*sympatico*

Merriam Webster:

> ...   agreeable, likable ... being on the same wavelength

Comment: We appreciate your answer. You can make this a better answer by providing links, even in answers responding to seemingly opinion-based questions.